# CSS text starting from a wrong place

Tags: html, css

This might be a stupid question, but it has been troubling me a lot.
I have made 4 boxes and each box should have the text starting from a same line, but sometimes (when the text is less), it starts from the bottom.

Here's the image displaying it:
[image]

Ideally, it should start from the top and go till the bottom. Like this:

[image]

What changes should I make in my CSS code?

CSS :-

```
.show-text {
  margin-left: 264px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 15em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #606060;
}

.show-text-col-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 15em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #606060;
}

.show-text-col-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 15em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #606060;
}

.show-text-col-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 15em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #606060;
}
```

My JSFiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/xa0obvyr/

Comment: Why do you have so many identical classes?

Comment: Post you html too and if you make fiddle that would be much better

Comment: @Richa, here's my fiddle. Doesn't display correctly in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/xa0obvyr/

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks
This was the best way I could think for my purpose. How would you do it?

Comment: You should use one class for HTML elements that have the same CSS style applied.

Comment: vertical-align: top for inline-blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need? with one CSS class and automatic 1/4 width of each column.

Please check the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sk1rqxeo/

```
.show-text-col {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #606060;
    width:24.5%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This works but I would suggest a small change. `display: inline-block;` is no longer needed as setting `float: left;` automatically makes the element `display: block;`. Alternatively you could replace `float: left;` with `vertical-align: top;` (keeping `display: inline-block;`) for the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `inline-block`, you need to specify vertical alignment if the default value doesn't suit you. In this case, you need

```
show-text-col-4 {vertical-align: top;}
```

However, your setup is less than ideal. Rather than floating the first time with a large left margin, I'd recommend you use a centered wrapper element instead, and style each of the columns in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set width to `<p>` tag

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xa0obvyr/1/)**

```
.show-text-col-3 p{
    width:200px;
}
```